"Large scale structure of spacetime", page 16: "the length of $V$ can be determined by $V(t)=1$"
On page 16 of the book The large scale structure of spacetime by Hawking and Ellis the authors  discuss the definition of a tangent space:

so the space of all tangent vectors to $\mathcal{M}$ at $p$, denoted by $T_p(\mathcal{M})$ or simply $T_p$, is an $n$-dimensional vector space. This space, representing the set of all directions at $p$, is called the tangent vector space to $\mathcal{M}$ at $p$. One may think of a vector $\mathbf{V} \in T_p$, as an arrow at $p$, pointing in the direction of a curve $\lambda(t)$ with tangent vector $\mathbf{V}$ at $p$, the 'length' of $\mathbf{V}$ being determined by the curve parameter $t$ through the relation $V(t) = 1$. (As $\mathbf{V}$ is an operator, we print it in bold type; its components $V^j$, and the number $V(f)$ obtained by $\mathbf{V}$ acting on a function $f$, are numbers, and so are printed in italics.)

I don't understand how the length of $\mathbf{V}$ can be determined.
$V(t)=1$, means $V^j(Dt/Dx^j)=1$, assuming $x^j(\lambda(t))$ is known for the mapping curve $\lambda(t)$ to local coordinates $x^j$, then $Dt/Dx^j$ is known, but it seems this equation alone can not determine all $V^j$ components. I am confused. Please help.

Please use MathJax to make your equations legible.

And in any case, name the equation you're talking about. We're all probably already familiar with it.
